# Mobile browsers unable to load base64 data uri for an <audio> tag

Tags: html, mobile, audio, base64, html5-audio

I am trying to cache audio by serving it from the server as a base64 encoded text file. For example:

```
<audio src="data:audio/mp3;base64,//MkxAA......."></audio>
```

This approach works fine on desktop browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and IE10. However it does not work on mobile browsers. After debugging the web page on a mobile device the request is simply cancelled by the browser (tested on Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Stock Android Browser).

Does anyone know why this is occurring? I would be happy to let this go if I could understand the reason behind it and make sure I am not missing something!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this is the case: "To avoid patent issues, support for MPEG 4, H.264, MP3 and AAC is not built directly into Firefox on desktop and mobile (Android and Firefox OS). Instead it relies on support from the OS or hardware...". [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Passerby. Unfortunately I don't think is the case as I tried a WAV encoded into base64 and this too suffered the same symptoms - works on desktop but a cancelled request in the mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be a hardware issue. Depending on the size of the audio file, the browser may ignore it to conserve system memory.