# Swiffy - Audio no longer functioning on iPad/Tablet//Mobile

Tags: audio, mobile, swiffy

I exported a SWF file using Swiffy a few months back and the audio functions.
http://www.vgidownload.co.uk/Tests/Old.html

Exporting the same file now results in no audio function.
http://www.vgidownload.co.uk/Tests/New.html

Is there something i'm missing here or has something changed between v7.1 and v7.4.

If so is there any way I can have the file export using v7.1 ?

The sound seems to function fine when viewd on a PC through a browser, it is just on iPad/Mobile that it is silent.

Thanks

Matt

---

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested Old.html on an iPad/Mobile? I just did and there's no sound. Also no sound in Chrome on Galaxy Core Prime. On the same Samsung in the android browser no test was possible because the "START" button doesn't work. Such are the limitations of swiffy on mobiles.

The sound is encoded in Base 64 in the swiffy html file, as are the images. But I could never get the audio to play on mobiles.  Further info: [How to make audio in swiffy HTML5 files play in mobile browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339220/how-to-get-swiffy-to-loop-music/32426455#32426455) or 
[Mobile browsers unable to load base64 data uri for an `<audio>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428326/mobile-browsers-unable-to-load-base64-data-uri-for-an-audio-tag?rq=1).

Comment: Hi,Yes I just tested the Old.html on my android phone and the audio functions ok, it also functions on the iPad.

Comment: I originally tested Old.html on iPad in Chrome and there was no sound. But I tested it again. Still no sound in Chrome, but it plays in Safari, On the Galaxy, it also plays in Chrome. I'm surprised because I gave up on swiffy ages ago over the no-sound-on-mobiles issue.

Comment: How about the new version?

Comment: If you mean your New.html version, no sound in Chrome or Safari on iPad. On the Samsung also mute in Chrome.

Comment: further to... Today I exported a 2MB swiffy html file from a FLA with lots of event sounds and a start button. No sound at all on iPad (Chrome, Safari) and Samsung (Chome, Android). Maybe your Old.html was a miracle?